# How do I disallow multiple instances of the chrome extension I developed from running?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am creating a new V3 chrome extension only that only runs for the URL: [www.abc.com/xyz](http://www.abc.com/xyz) URL.  The extension contains the standard popup when you click the extensions' icon near the address bar.

Now if the user duplicates the tab at [www.abc.com/xyz](http://www.abc.com/xyz) there would be two tabs open both with their own popups.  I want to make it so the extension (e.g. popup.html) is not visible (or it can be disabled) in that new tab since another instance is already running.

For context the popup.html contains the start button that does all the magic for the extension.  I do not want users to be able to click start in multiple tabs.  I need to be able to detect if duplicate tab is open and disable the popup so that the popup shows in the original tab only.

Is this possible to do via a manifest entry or do I need to code it somehow?  If I need to code it can someone offer any ideas on how that would be done?
Thank-you.

Comment: If popup.html is inside the web page, you'll have to control its presence yourself e.g. by sending a message first and if there's no response proceed to add the UI.

Comment: We need more information to properly help you. It's not clear what you are asking to do. Have you attempted anything yet? When a user opens [a popup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/user_interface/Popups) and then switches tabs the popup normally closes. This question needs more clarity.

Comment: @justinw will add some more details thanks for feedback